# Service not function in Sweetalert

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I know this has been asked before but I can't seem to find the answer, I want to ask about `sweetalert` not function in my component in `sweetalert` include service for delete a data.

[image]

**Component**

```
Swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: 'You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
    cancelButtonText: 'No, keep it'
}).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
        this.bookingService.deletedata(data._id).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
        Swal(
            'Deleted!',
            'Your imaginary file has been deleted.',
            'success'
        )
    } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
        Swal(
            'Cancelled',
            'Your imaginary file is safe :)',
            'error'
        )
    }
})
```

**Service**

```js
deletedata(param) {
        console.log(param);
        let searchUrl = Urlapi + '/pesan/remove' + param;
        return this.http.delete(searchUrl, this.jwt()).map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Comment: post the code for bookingService

Comment: code in my qustion

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign let me = this; at the start of function.

```
let me = this;

Swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: 'You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
    cancelButtonText: 'No, keep it'
}).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
        me.bookingService.deletedata(data._id).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
        Swal(
            'Deleted!',
            'Your imaginary file has been deleted.',
            'success'
        )
    } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
        Swal(
            'Cancelled',
            'Your imaginary file is safe :)',
            'error'
        )
    }
})
```